# How to compare vectors in simple and effecient way?

Tags: c++, loops, data-structures, vector, comparison

I wanted to write a program that compares `vector` `a` with `vector` `b`. And if `vector` `a` is a sub vector of `vector` `b` then return `true` else `false`.
For example:

```
vector a is 1,2,3
```

and
`vector b is 2,3,4,1,1,2,3,56`.

So it should be in a contiguous block.
And I wrote this nasty code but I want to write this in short way. I don't want to declare any global variables for this problem.

```
bool i_vec(vector<int>& a, vector<int>  b)
    {
        vector<int> index ( b.size(),0 );
        int counter = 0;

       // if ( a.size() <= b.size() ) {

            for ( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
                for ( int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++ ) {
                    if ( a[i]== b[j]) {
                        index[j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for ( int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++ ) {
                if ( index[i] == 1 ) {
                    for ( int j = i; j < index.size(); j++ ) {
                        if ( index[j] == 1 ) {
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(counter == a.size()){
                        //cout<<"true"<<endl;

                        return true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        counter = 0;
                        cout<<"false"<<endl;
                        return false;
                      //  continue;
                    }

                }
            }
       // }
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `return std::search(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end()) != b.end();` Short way, and no global variables.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Should that line be sufficient?

Comment: If you want to look into efficient implementations of this you can read up on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: this is essentially a string search algorithm. if you want an efficient implementation, look into Boyer-Moore

Comment: `Should that line be sufficient?` Have you tried it, and found it lacking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using stl algorithm.It's efficient and also makes things sample.

```
bool i_vec(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i <= b.size() - a.size(); i++)
    {
        if(equal(a.begin(), a.end(), &b[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::search` instead of this entire `for` loop and `std::equal` solution?

Comment: @Blastfurnace So is that a iterative solution?

Comment: @user4032883: Yes it is. [This documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) shows its complexity and an example implementation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace So which one is more efficient?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Also I have one more question that has not been answered yet. Could you help me with that.

Comment: @user4032883: 1) I would use `std::search`. This code is _sort of_ the same idea but `std::search` is short, correct, and better expresses what you want. 2) If you have a follow-up question post a new question and include a link to this question to provide context.

Comment: @Blastfurnace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353821/need-to-modify-my-recursive-algorithm