# Need to modify my recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector

This is a subset sum problem and its working properly but I am having an issue. I need to initialize z=0 in the main. But is there a way that I could do it without initializing z=0 in the main.

So according to the main it should return true because according to subset sum problem, the sum of the elements in the vector in any combination should be equal to target.

```
 bool r_x(vector<int> myvec, int y, int z=0){

        if( y == 0 )
            return true;

        if( z > myvec.size()-1)
            return false;

        return r_x(myvec, y, z+1) || r_x(myvec, y-myvec[z], z+1);
    }
int main(){
int z;
int y=7;

 vector<int> myvec;
    myvec.push_back(3);
    myvec.push_back(1);
    myvec.push_back(1);
    myvec.push_back(4);

r_x(vector<int> myvec, int z, int y);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
true
```

The output should be true but its like this.

Comment: I find your question unclear. What's the exact issue you're trying to solve? Why can't you call `r_x` with `z=0`?

Comment: I take it front-loading this with a wrapper or a default-argument is not allowed? And regardless, did you really *intend* to pass that vector by-value over and over (and over..) again ?

Comment: I want to run the program without initializing z=0 in the main.
But with the code I have written I have to write z=0 in the main.

Comment: So reorder your args: `bool r_x(vector<int> const& myvec, int y, int z=0)` and the calls within `r_x`, and don't bother providing anything besides the vector and y arguments from `main()`. And it would help *immensely* if you showed both how you're *currently* calling this from `main()`, and how you *want* to call this from `main()`, with **real code**.

Comment: I tried that already but its not working

Comment: Then you didn't do it right, because that will do *exactly* what you want if you do all *three* things i said: (1) swap the order of y and z arguments, (2) provide z a default value of 0, and finally (3) change the calls within `r_x` so they honor the new parameter list. The latter is likely what you missed: `return r_x(myvec, y, z+1) || r_x(myvec, y-myvec[z], z+1);` Doing all the above should allow you to simply call `r_x(myvec, y)` from `main()`. You **still** have not updated the question with the current, and desired call methods used from `main()`, so that hasn't exactly help to clarify.

Comment: oh yeah it worked I was not doing r_x(myvec, y) rather I was doing r_x(myvec, y, z).

Comment: But still i am having one problem. If call r_x(myvec, y) function in main it only shows true and if I call r_x(myvec, y, z) in main it shows false all the time.

Comment: @user4032883 Post the code (and data) that you're calling the function with. It would also be nice to provide a hint about what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo I posted it.

Comment: @user4032883 1) You never initialise `z`. It's very likely that whatever random value it has is greater than `myvec.size() - 1`. 2) Even if you had initialised it, that code doesn't compile. Don't retype code from memory - copy and paste. 3) Provide examples of data where the function returns the wrong value.

Comment: @user4032883 1) The code still doesn't compile, let alone run. 2) Even if it did, that's not the output from that program. 3) Are we supposed to guess what input goes with each output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach to this is to wrap the recursive function in a non-recursive function

```
bool r_x_recursive(vector<int> myvec, int z, int y){

    if( y == 0 )
        return true;

    if( z > myvec.size()-1)
        return false;

    return r_x(myvec, z+1, y) || r_x(myvec, z+1, y-myvec[z]);
}

bool r_x(vector<int> myvec, int y) {
   return r_x_recursive(myvec, 0, y);
}
```

now you can just call `r_x(vec,3)`.

Comment: When I do it like this it show me an error undeclcared identifier r_x.